# Design/Implementation advice on XML Parsing with multiple connections/feeds/views

Tags: ios, design-patterns, xml-parsing

Starting my first iOS project and wanted to advice on how to structure the application.
The app pulls a XML feed, parses it out and displays a list representing the items in the XML feed. When clicking on a item in the list the app will pull a new XML feed using one of the attributes from the previously pulled XML feed. This happens several layers of pull, parse, display and on user selection do the same thing over again. Now most of the XML element structure is something like this:

(These are simple examples just to demonstrate what's going on)

- http://site.com/get/items/

returns (Display info on new view):

```
<items>
    <item id="123" name="item 1" />
    <item id="124" name="item 2" />
    <item id="125" name="item 3" />
</itmes>
```

- http://site.com/get/description/123 (Example user has selected item 1, make call to get description)

returns:

```
<itemDescription>
    <description itemId="123" name="desc 1" description="blah 1" />
</itemDescription>
```

Wanted to know:

- Should I have a connection class/object or a new connection in each view?
- Should I have a parser class/object or parse the XML feed in each view?
- I'm also looking to store some of the data returned so I don't need to call the XML feed again if the user navigates back to the main items list, but I would need to parse the itemsDescription XML feed every time.

I've looked at several tutorials on parsing XML and I get the gist of how to do this, wanting to focus more of the design and reusability instead of duplicating the code over in each new view. Or am I way off on how this works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way you can do this following Apple Guidelines is checking one of their examples, some months ago I made an app similar to yours following this example. Also you can see how to make your app in offline mode.

### [Basic structure](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007323) (w/o offline mode):

> The SeismicXML sample application demonstrates how to use NSXMLParser
>   to parse XML data. When you launch the application it downloads and
>   parses an RSS feed from the United States Geological Survey (USGS)
>   that provides data on recent earthquakes around the world. It displays
>   the location, date, and magnitude of each earthquake, along with a
>   color-coded graphic that indicates the severity of the earthquake. The
>   XML parsing occurs on a background thread using NSOperation and
>   updates the earthquakes table view with batches of parsed objects.

### [Advanced structure](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ThreadedCoreData/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010723) (with offline mode):

> Demonstrates how to use Core Data in a multi-threaded environment,
>   following the first recommended pattern mentioned in the Core Data
>   Programming Guide.
>
> Based on the SeismicXML sample, it downloads and parses an RSS feed
>   from the United States Geological Survey (USGS) that provides data on
>   recent earthquakes around the world. What makes this sample different
>   is that it persistently stores earthquakes using Core Data. Each time
>   you launch the app, it downloads new earthquake data, parses it in an
>   NSOperation which checks for duplicates and stores newly founded
>   earthquakes as managed objects.
>
> For those new to Core Data, it can be helpful to compare SeismicXML
>   sample with this sample and notice the necessary ingredients to
>   introduce Core Data in your application.

Regarding cwieland answer I wouldn't use ASIHTTPRequest because is [outdated](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;), so if you want to follow his approach I would recomend you to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking), where you can handle an XML request easy and fast:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.groups.browse&api_key=b6300e17ad3c506e706cb0072175d047&cat_id=34427469792%40N01&format=rest"]];
AFXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {
  XMLParser.delegate = self;
  [XMLParser parse];
} failure:nil];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
[queue addOperation:operation];
```

Comment: +1 for "I wouldn't use ASIHTTPRequest because is outdated, so if you want to follow his approach I would recomend you to use AFNetworking"

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would implement it. I would use ASIHTTPRequest for all connection items and not worry about that part of it. It can handle all of your downloading of data asynchronous very easily with simple delegate methods.

I would have a parser class that takes in the url, downloads it asynchronously, and then parses the data returned. It would then return the array of parsed children through a delegate method to a tableview that would display the children in the xml data.

I would create a subclass of UITableViewController that will handle any url/data type in which case you'd only have to write up one tableview class and not worry about how the user navigates through. This would make it so that you only need to write one class and it would handle any number of drill downs or combinations. This implementation depends heavily on how complicated the distinct levels of xml data is. If they are drastically different it would make more sense to have cleaner code in the tableview and not have `if's` checking on the type of data in the cell creation.

Using a navigation style app would eliminate the need to re-parse the data each time the view loads as you pop views off the stack. Anytime going forward though it would be re-parsing but a simple cache of the urls->array could solve this if needed/wanted. It would require the reloading of the data each time the app launches though. Of course if you received a memory warning 3 levels deep it would require a re-parse or cache retrieval on your way back up.

If you are wanting a caching system I would write a class that goes in-between the view controllers and the url parser that checks the store and if it is in there return the array of data otherwise return nil and go get it.

I personally would use NSXMLParser as that is what I'm familiar with. You may want to house the elements in a class wrapper in which case you would just have to check which type of element you have on `didStartElement` and set an enum to switch on through creation. that is pretty easy with nsxmlparser. I haven't used any other parser to compare with but did find that debugging NSXMLParser was simple enough and coding was straightforward so it wasn't to hard to get it up and running. Here is a great site on all the different xml parsers:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

So in summary I would have a subclass of NSObject that accepts the url, downloads it through ASIHTTPRequest, parses it. A Sublcass of UITableviewController that on the cell tap it allocates the same view controller class with the new url and pushes it on the navigation stack. The view would show a loading screen until the array is returned and then just reload the data. It would be a very DRY KISS hopefully.

I would house as much of the code in global classes as possible. If each pull of data there is only one main category, as in

```
<items>
    <stuff></stuff>
    ....
    <stuff></stuff>
</items>
EOF
```

I would use an array to house all the values, If there is more than one main section I would store everything in a dictionary with the parent attribute as the key and the values in an array. Then on the tableview have different sections based on the keys of the dictionaries.

I hope this answers some of your questions. I'm not sure how low of level you were looking for. I speak from developing quite a few apps and writing a RSS reader. Let me know if there is anything you'd like me to clarify.

Comment: WOW! Very nice and detailed +1